# Angular 4: Class with constructor as http Observable model

Tags: angular, typescript

In my app, I have a model defined as Class with a constructor. Like this:

```
export class Movie {
    title: string;
    posterURL: string;
    description: string;

    public constructor(cfg: Partial<Movie>) {
        Object.assign(this, cfg);
    }

    getEndDate(): Date {
        return new Date();
    }
};
```

I also have an HTTP request that uses this model

```
getMoviesData(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.http.get<Movie[]>(`http://localhost:3544/movies`)
}
```

As expected, it doesn't work

How can I solve this? Should I also create an interface or what?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpClient` methods are generic, `this.http.get<Movie[]>` asserts that the result conforms to `Movie[]` interface and doesn't create `Movie` instances.

In order for the result to become class instances, the class should be explicitly instantiated. Class constructor should preferably accept plain object which properties will be assigned to class instance, and `Movie` already does this with `cfg` parameter.

Since it's unlikely that `Partial<Movie>` type precisely describes the interface, it's better to declare a separate interface:

```
interface IMovie {
    title: string;
    posterURL: string;
    description: string;
}

class Movie implements IMovie { ... }

...

getMoviesData(): Observable<Movie[]> {
    return this.http.get<IMovie[]>(...)
    .map(plainMovies => plainMovies.map(plainMovie => new Movie(plainMovie)))
}
```