# Map JSON to TypeScript Class using HttpClient Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I want to use the HttpClient to make an API call and map the response to and class (not interface), I want that class to have certain methods with i can extend and later call in the HTML views.

I don't know why this isn't working as expected but it seems like it isn't possible for the HttpClient to map my json to classes.

The error that I get is:
`test is not a function`

I'm trying to do this as followed:

User.ts

```
export class User {
  id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;
  groups: Group[];

  test() {
    return 'test';
  }
}
```

Api.Service.ts

```
export class ApiService {

  private base_url: String = environment.api;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public me() {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.base_url + `user/me`);
  }
}
```

html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="user | async; else loading; let user">
    {{user.test()}}
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>
    loading...
</ng-template>
```

controller:

```
export class UserController implements OnInit {

    user: Observable<User>;

    constructor(private api: ApiService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.user = this.api.me()
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177015/angular-4-class-with-constructor-as-http-observable-model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up defining this in my class:

```
static fromJSON(data: any) {
    return Object.assign(new this, data);
}
```

Which will map the values correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following my frined:

```
export class User {
id: number;
first_name: string;
last_name: string;
groups: Group[];

test() {
  return 'test';
}

static fromJSON(json) {
    const user: User = new User();
    user.id = json.id;
    user.first_name = json.first_name;
    user.last_name = json.last_name;
    user.groups = [];

    json.groups.forEach(group => {
        user.groups.push(Group.fromJSON(group));
    });

    return user;
}
```

}

```
export class ApiService {

    private base_url: String = environment.api;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public me() {
      return this.http.get<User>(this.base_url + `user/me`).map(data => User.fromJSON(data.json()));
    }
}
```

You must add the same method 'fromJSON' to the 'Group' class in order to create a new Group object from the json.groups.

Comment: I'm using the new HttpClient from Angular which doesn't support .json() anymore, besides that I'm using `http.get<User>` so the response gets automatically mapped to the structure of my class. But the problem is that the HttpClient doesn't create a class (probably because of the JavaScript runtime).